# Sorting an arrayref of hashes

Tags: perl, sorting, perl-data-structures

I'm having trouble trying to sort a arrayref of hashes based on a value in the hash, the data structure looks like this:

```
my %usera = (name => 'tom',
             weight=> 10);
my %userb = (name => 'harry',
             weight=> 1);
my %userc = (name => 'peter',
             weight=> 5);
my $users = [];
push(@$users,\%usera,\%userb,\%userc);
```

I want to sort the results by weight decending, so it would come back in the order of "Tom,Peter,Harry", but I haven't had a lot of luck. I tried:

```
for my $user (sort{ $users->[$a]{'Weight'} <=> $users->[$b]{'Weight'} } @$users){
    .....
}
```

Which I thought might have worked, but no love there.

Any idea?

TIA!

Comment: Define `"come back"`, please. Do you mean that you printed the values inside the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sorting `@$users`, your pipelined data comes in terms of *elements* not *subscripts*. So, indexing into `$users->[$x]` is completely unnecessary, not to mention *wrong*. If you had used `warnings`, you would have seen `Use of reference "HASH(0x2c201e0)" as array index at ...` Change your sort to:

```
use warnings;

foreach my $user (sort { $b->{weight} <=> $a->{weight} } @$users ) {
    ...
}
```

Also, as mentioned elsewhere Perl hashes are case sensitive. `$h->{Weight}` and `$h->{weight}` are two different hash slots.

Comment: Thanks Axeman, exactly what I needed. Sorry about the case issue, that was just me typing out some code and copy and pasting another. Thanks again!

Comment: @Analog, glad I could help. Funny thing is that I've been doing a bit of .NET programming lately (cap city) and I didn't notice the cap issue right away.

Answer (score 2):

The [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) function receives a block that can be adjusted to your needs. Two implicit variables (`$a` and `$b`) are used to indicate 'left' and 'right' values for sorting. Thus, the following code should do what you need:

```
my @sorted = sort { $b->{weight} <=> $a->{weight} } @$users;
```

And this will sort by name (note the `cmp` operator instead of the *spaceship* operator):

```
my @sorted = sort { $a->{name} cmp $b->{name} } @$users;
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl is case-sensitive. Try:

```
foreach my $user (sort { $users->[$a]{'weight'} <=> $users->[$b]{'weight'} } @$users ) {
.....
}
```

Comment: `$users->[$a]` will give the error `Use of reference as array index`, because `@$users` is not a list of indexes.